# Redirect with htaccess to https imperfect

Tags: javascript, php, css, apache, .htaccess

I redirect from http to https using .htaccess.
But the page is not successfully loaded perfectly because I use a script as below to load external files.

```
<script src = "http://domain.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text / css" href = "http://domain.com/file.css">
```

How can I make loading can be perfect, without the need to change the address in the file src and href?
This script .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond% {HTTP_HOST} ^ www \. (. *) $ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ (. *) $ Http: //% 1 / $ 1 [R = 301, L]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteCond% {HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (. *) Https: //% {HTTP_HOST}% {REQUEST_URI} [R, L]

</ IfModule>
```

**Nb: Prior added the following script in .htaccess, opened pages can be perfect, but of course I want the website automatically redirect to https**

```
RewriteCond% {HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (. *) Https: //% {HTTP_HOST}% {REQUEST_URI} [R, L]
```

Comment: Don't include the protocol in the src and href tag. If you do it won't work because it will try and load http and the browser will block it. you need to either change it to a non protocol specific path or change it to https.

Comment: @PanamaJack is correct - load your JS, CSS, and all other assets without using protocol specific paths, or you can load dependent upon the active path: eg - `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//css/mystyles.css">`